# Embeded YouTube Question (Java/Scripting)

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

First post here so let me know if something is done the wrong way, however.

I've never taken into account what it would actually take to do this, but to make a long story short, There's a section of my website that I'm creating for Class Work that I want to resemble "Rainymood.com"

RainyMood is a website in which there is a looping 30m audio file (which I have already) as well as "Daily Song Picks" that can play simultaneously with the rain ambiance to create peaceful sounds by simply attaching the youtube video you have in mind to the end of the URL

For example, changing "https://RainyMood.com" to "https://rainymood.com/watch?v=ZBrT97qJ-3w" changes the source of the embedded youtube video to play Sasuke's Theme from the Naruto OST

I've looked around for how to do this but I haven't found what I was looking for.
I have a basic understanding of Javascript but I'm not sure where to even begin with this one.

Comment: Welcome :) The answer to this very simple and can be achieved by so many ways, the simplest could be,  replacing the video ID (coming from your URL) in your youtube iframe on your HTML page :) There are many javascript libraries which can manipulate dom for you - In addition please read this before posting https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what do you mean by `Java/Scripting` ?  I will be really astonished that there can exist an interpreted version of java used to carry out scripts!  otherwise what you are asking looks more like url rewriting, and it concerns your server (apache? ngnix?)

Comment: Ali- thanks for the response and the post for the correct way to go about asking, thank you very much

Comment: Mister Jojo- I'm not necessarily saying the two are linked I'm just saying I kinda assumed the answer dealt with either or. There's a script I run simply to change the volume when the page loads. I'm not sure of the extent of what you can do with it

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple copy that's functionally similar to the one used on rainymood.com with just a few lines of HTML. All you need is an `audio` tag, `source` tag, and an `iframe` tag. Put your audio source in the `source` tag as shown, and place your embedded Youtube link in the `iframe` as shown.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <audio controls loop>
       <source src="https://rainymood.com/audio1112/0.m4a" type="audio/mp4" />
    </audio>

    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZBrT97qJ-3w" allowfullscreen="">. 
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to make your own audio player using Javascript, then take a look at [this tutorial](https://freshman.tech/custom-html5-video/). Although it's for making a video player, the same concepts apply to controlling audio as well.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Would the same trick work with how it does on that site? They, for example, have <href> tags that are what comes after the "Watch?v=" bit. When you click on them it loads a new page with that videos extension or you can add any one you find and it'll pull that video up directly. I assumed 2 things were happening. Either, there were pages for each video(which wouldn't make sense because you can add your own and that would be a lot of work) or that there's a way to write script in a way that updates the source of the embedded video from what comes after ".com/"

Comment: @iSupakilla They are probably parsing the query string of the url to get the video id. So like in the example above, they would extract `v=ZBrT97qJ-3w` and use the value of `v` to embded the youtube video with that specific id. That would take a little bit of Javascript to pull off, but it's not too difficult. Consider it as a research problem to try and replicate it :)